# how to add and delete <Object> from (and to) LiveData<List<Object>>?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, rx-java2, android-livedata

I have a recyclerView which is filled with LiveData<List> currentList.
I take Single<List> and add person using currentList.setValue(people) in onSuccess method (see code below).
But when I open the app, there is just 1 object in the recyclerView.
My task is:
1) when app is open it has to add 4 persons to recyclerView (i.e. to currentList);
2) after onSwipe method it has to delete 1st  and add 1 new random  from RoomDatabase to the end of currentList.

It means that I need methods which are deleting  and adding objects to LiveData<List>.
How can I do this? (ViewModel code is below)

```
public class PersonViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private PersonRepository mRepository;
    private CompositeDisposable composite = new CompositeDisposable();
    private Single<List<Person>> mGuyWho;     // это нада??? LOBNYA
    private Single<Person> mGuy;      // PSKOV
    private MutableLiveData<List<Person>> currentList = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public PersonViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new PersonRepository(application);

        mGuyWho = mRepository.getGuyWho(); //это нада?? LOBNYA
        mGuy = mRepository.getGuy(); // PSKOV

        mGuyWho.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())   // LOBNYA nachalo
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<Person>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSubscribe(Disposable d): called");
                        composite.add(d);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<Person> people) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: called");
                        currentList.setValue(people); // here I pass List to LiveData<List>
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onError: called");
                        Toast.makeText(application, "NO DATA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });  // LOBNYA konets

        mGuy.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Person>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSubscribe(Disposable d): called");
                        composite.add(d);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Person person) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: called");
                        currentList.setValue(person); // there is an error, for I cannot bypass <Person> to LiveData<List<>>
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onError: called");
                    }
                })
        }
    LiveData<List<Person>> getCurrentList() {
        return currentList;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LiveData` is composed of a `List<Person>` object:

```
private MutableLiveData<List<Person>> currentList = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

In your `onSuccess()` method, you are trying to pass it a `Person` object. You should instead pass `mutableListOf(Person())` in there for it to work. ***However, this still won't solve your problem.***

What you need to do is the following:

1. Receive the ViewHolder's `onSwipe` event and call the `remove` method in your `viewModel`.
2. This `remove` method should modify your `currentList` by removing the element. You can pass an `id` to `remove` method to make things easier.
3. Because `currentList` is `LiveData` every `observer` will be notified.
4. Then you need to fetch the random entry from `Room Database`.
5. Add this random entry to `currentList`. You can use the `Transformations` API of `LiveData` for this.
6. Once again, because `currentList` is `LiveData`, every `Observer` will be notified.

Comment: thank you much.
yet how remove method in ViewModel should look like? (given that I have to remove from Livedata<>)

Comment: `private MutableLiveData<List<Person>> currentList = new MutableLiveData<>();`

`List` in nature is not `mutable` i.e. addition and deletion are not possible. To achieve that, its better to use `ArrayList`. You will simply be able to call `currentList.remove(element)` on the list then.

Comment: my adapter does not understand which item is deleted by swipe. When I do swipe, current <Person>  is updated and deleted; but when I swipe next, <Person> is updated and deleted from <List>, but not from View; at the same time the third <Person> is deleted from View (because adapter tries to find item #1 but not #0, while after deleting item #0, item #1 has become item #0, and respectively item #2 has become item #1, but adapter doesn't know this, I don't understand how to synchronize this..)

Comment: You don't setup these actions on the `adapter` as `adapter's` job is to manage the `List` itself, and not the `elements`. Setup these `onClickListeners` in the `ViewHolder` class. Your `ViewHolder` will have the `Person` element.

A clean solution is to create a `EventListener` interface. Pass this `EventListener` as an `argument` to the `adapter`. The `EventListener` instance will obviously be your `viewModel`. Also in the `onBindInstance()` method of `RecyclerView`, pass `EventListener` to the `ViewHolder` as well, and hence you will have your `viewModel` instance in your `ViewHolder`.

Comment: Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69C1ljfDvl0&t=592s).

Comment: Now the problem is that in this example common OnClickListener is used, which I can implement in ViewHolder.
But in my case there is CardStackListener interface (onSwipe() is one of its methods), which is an atribute of CardStackLayoutManager, which I set to CardstackView (a library that extends RecyclerView) in MainActivity: ```myCardStackLayoutManager = new CardStackLayoutManager(this, /*here I put listener instance*/);``` and ```myCardStackView.setLayoutManager(myCardStackLayoutManager);``` And I don't understant thus how can I call onSwipe in ViewHolder.

Comment: `onClick` is simply a method exposed by the `onClickListener`. You can (and should) create your own `Listener`, which will be you creating your own `API` for what your `views` can and should do.

Create one Interface with all the swipe, or clicks, or long clicks that you want. Then make your `viewHolders` implement that interface. That will force your views to follow it strictly. Anything that your `viewHolders` will need, for example `viewModel`, pass that through whatever the `CardStackView` `adapter` is.